Firebase google sign in OAuth - [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] access_token audience is not for this project -Flutter
I am creating google sign-in OAuth for my flutter app, First I created a Firebase project with 2 android apps (Members app and admins app) which is having same SHA keys which I figured out later. It gave me the error as

"[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] access_token audience is not for
this project"

I searched in old posts and I thought it's about SHA key problem. So I deleted the debug.keystore and regenerated. Still it didn't work.
So I created another project with only one app (Members app) by generating brand new SHA-1 key. Still it's showing the same error.

"[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] access_token audience is not for
this project"

FYI: I have checked the OAuth clientId in the google-services.json file i am downloading everytime and it's matching with the google cloud console.
Future<void> login() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) {
        return;
      }
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print('Login failed: $error');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Login failed: $error')),
      );
    }
  }

This is the code for login function.
Thankyou so much for helping me out.
Please add comments if I miss out something on explaining my problem.
